# Tag Overflow – interactive exploration of Stack Exchange tags

Tags: discussion, tags

(Taken from [this Meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248579/tagoverflow-interactive-exploration-of-stack-exchange-tags) and adapted for SFF.)

[image]

These are the 32 most popular tags, with size proportional to the popularity of the tag. Edges represent the relationship between tags. Width is related to the number of questions with both tags, while shade compares how often they occur together compared to what you’d expect if tags were distributed randomly.

Made with [TagOverflow](https://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=scifi&size=32).

**ETA:** Some people have been complaining that this isn’t a question. *rolleyes*

Pretty cool, huh?

Comment: Interesting stuff.

Comment: Why does choosing more than 32 tags have a "`warning SE might block you`"?

Comment: @Mooz it’s making lots of requests to the Stack Exchange API at once, which can look like the start of a DDOS or similar, so they block your IP address temporarily. (And yes, I got blocked while playing with it. Oops.)

Comment: I find it fascinating to consider the density and placement of questions in relationship to each other. It would seem that identification of stories is still the primary purpose of this site, along with the most popular sci-fi franchises of Star Trek, Star Wars, Harry Potter, Game of Thrones and DC/Marvel Comics as the lynchpins. Thanks for sharing your discovery @alexwlchan.

Comment: Primarily opinion based! Although there is no line between Star Trek and time travel - which invites snide thoughts on the abramsverse... I like that! +1, man!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is cool.

[image]