# Map of all 2,355 tags

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6618), I created a map of all tags on the site.

I used some [software](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki) from the same person who made the [TagOverflow](http://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=scifi&size=32) online tool. This tool uses a [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/478702?RatioCap=1000&NumTags=10000&MinTagCount=1&MinOERatio=2.5&MinTagPairCount=1) query, so it isn’t limited by API requests like the online tool is.

## 2017 map of everything

The coloring is mostly arbitrary. That outer ring of tags is a bunch of tags that had no connections to any other tag, so they’re just out by themselves. The image links to an SVG version of the file, for better zooming.

[image: 2017 map of all tags]

## 2017 map of all tags used at least 15 times

Here is a map of all tags that are used at least 15 times. The color scheme is not quite the same as the previous map.

[image: 2017 map of tags used 15+ times]

## 2016 map

Here is a map of all tags from 2016. This reflects the site’s tagging prior to the recent [Big Edit Event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10691).

[image: 2016 map of all tags]

To make this a question: any requests? I can generate SVG, different tags, different coloring, etc.

Comment: It’s easier to see all the connections in the software, since I can highlight particular nodes.

Comment: Apparently I'm very right-wing on this map.

Comment: Is it possible to have a larger map with all the tags, not just the biggest?

Comment: @Eithne It’s kind of possible. [Here](http://yellowantphil.com/all.png). 176 tags refused to group with any of the others. For example, all [tag:falling-skies] questions have only that tag.

Comment: @anaranjada, thank you so much! It's really interesting to see how all the topics are related or not to each others. It's like to see whole achipelagos, little islands and some big, major continents of a world.

Comment: @anaranjada WOW. I'm going to frame that and put it on my wall.

Comment: wow, that's great I do so love organization

Comment: Awesome job, it looks amazing :-)

Comment: It's 2017, surely?

Comment: It's got *horns* now. Great bulging horns of fantasy.

Comment: I'd like to see this generated again, the last one is from 2017.

Comment: @Anonymous It probably hasn't changed much since 2017; we didn't have another Big Edit Event since then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hey, this was awesome.

[But, we killed it.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/the-big-edit-event-is-finished)

Would you do this for us again? You'll have to wait a week, though, in order for all of our changes to reflect on the Data Explorer:

> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC.

I'm eager to see some of the differences as part of the clean up.

---

Hey, if you're taking requests, I wouldn't mind seeing a cleaned-up version showing only tags > 15 questions, too, for readability.