# Favorite Questions and Answers from second quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2016 through June 30 2016 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/04/01)

**This time I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.** Might be nice for people to see those.

Comment: Is there some way you could search for all bounties awarded since 2016-04-01?  Those (at least the ones not on very old answers) are usually worth to mention, because at least the person who posted the bounty found the question or an answer their favorite.

Comment: There were 124 bounties awarded this last quarter, so probably too many to mention, however I'll note the number and rep total in the post.

Comment: For anyone interested, The full blog post for Highlights from second Quarter of 2016 can be found [here](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/07/highlights-from-2016-2nd-quarter/)

Answer (score 6):

I'll break convention and nominate a meta question:

- [Map of all 2,137 tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/map-of-all-2-137-tags)

  I like this question because it makes our tagging look awesome. Our messy tagging that's been known to cause arguments also creates a tag map with clusters of tags and surprising connections all over the place. Sites that enforce cleaner tagging sometimes have tag maps that look more sterile. Scroll through the tag map and revel in our messy tagging!

Answer (score 6):

I think that [Does Aragorn wear pants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132068/does-aragorn-wear-pants) is as important as whether [Balrog have wings](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Balrogs/Wings) (or [fuzzy slippers](http://flyingmoose.org/tolksarc/theories/slippers.htm)).

I also like [Why is the Star Wars universe not a post-scarcity economy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125624/why-is-the-star-wars-universe-not-a-post-scarcity-economy), although I might be seen as biased since I have the high vote on it.

Lastly, [Why have most Superhero movies ditched the "Secret Identity"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127181/why-have-most-superhero-movies-ditched-the-secret-identity) was entertaining to see how various people answered it on Word of God, sociological, and story-telling levels.

Comment: Nothing biased about liking your own questions/answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Questions**:

[Why didn't Harry use the right-hand-rule (or other methods) to solve the Triwizard maze?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/129816/51379)

We have over 3000 [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) questions. One that is genuinely thought-provoking is a rare find.

**Answers**:

[What are the advantages that come with knighthood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129570/51379)

This is a truly comprehensive answer.

[Did maps in Middle-Earth have west on the top?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131565/51379)

I seriously did not imagine any in-text answer to this question could exist, but this answer proved me wrong, and showed that Tolkien put much more thought into map orientations (or should I say occidentations?) than I gave him credit for.

Answer (score 2):

**Questions:**

1. [What do people in Westeros Eat during winter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132901/what-do-people-in-westeros-eat-during-winter)?

The amount of effort put into this Question is truly amazing. Loved reading it.

2. [Did Sansa Play Jon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132393/did-sansa-play-jon-season-6-eps-9-spoiler)

Not really high voted but a very well thought Question.

**Answers:**

1. [Why did Saruman attack Helm's Deep instead of Edoras?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131484/why-did-saruman-attack-helms-deep-instead-of-capturing-edoras/131663#131663)

I really enjoy reading answers which include maps and battle strategies, based in canon info of the franchise.

2. [Game of Thrones - Confusing Geography](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24948/game-of-thrones-confusing-geography/131151#131151)

Embarrassing entry because this is one of mine and not high voted either. But since we are talking about enjoying stuff so what the heck, I really enjoyed writing this answer and creating maps for it.

---

There are some other very good questions but I suppose 4 entries are enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Questions**

- [Why is The Matrix tinted green?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129319/why-is-the-matrix-tinted-green)
- [Why does everyone call Hagrid by his last name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129936/why-does-everyone-call-hagrid-by-his-last-name) (it's a thinker)
- [Why does Zaphod Beeblebrox call Ford Prefect "Ford" when they meet on the Heart of Gold?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131940/why-does-zaphod-beeblebrox-call-ford-prefect-ford-when-they-meet-on-the-heart) (because I noticed it years ago, but never remembered to ask it here)

**Answers**

- [Why is the Matrix tinted green](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129322/20774)
- [What happens to Fawkes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124193/20774)

Comment: @user14111 - not to be rude, but what would REALLY improve the site is if everyone stopped belittling the specific type of questions they personally find uninteresting. Live and let live.

Comment: @user14111 - touché! :)  I have definitely mellowed out about my opposition to ID Qs, since the early days - I still agree with Atwood's reasoning about them, but I stopped seeing them as detrimental to the site pretty early on. Ironically, I'm quite a fan of story-ID **answers**, mostly over the level and breath of expertise, knowledge and familiarity required to do them.

Comment: @user14111 - also, to set the record straight, I **never** advocated deleting them. My most strident complaint about them was that (1) people upvote them far higher than their worth appears to me personally, out of sheer bike-shedding; and (2) sometimes we get so many of them, that they crowd out non-ID questions from front page.

Comment: @user14111 - I don't think your opinion is common. I know of may be 5 people tops who'd quit the site if ID questions were prohibited, one of whom already did. I'm pretty sure there would be far more people who'd quit the site if ONLY ID questions were allowed. Mind you, I quit the site (in part) because synthesis/analysis questions aren't allowed, so what do I know?

Comment: My suggestion is that if people don't like a specific kind of question, they should use the "ignore-tag" function.

Comment: I suspect this answer was downvoted more because of who posted it than because people think the linked posts are bad. Have an upvote to compensate: I'm not a great fan of self-promotion, but they *are* good questions and answers.

Comment: @randal'thor - Meh. Jack posts the results regardless of votes so downvoting is pretty worthless.

Comment: I guess whatever was happening here was resolved. **Since I'm only asking for favorites, and that is personally subjective, all entries are used.** Additionally, I'm not asking for least favorites, because I'm not interested in people complaining about posts and propagating that. Occasionally I will shorten someone's list, but that is usually due to overlap between the top results or other posts (to eliminate redundancy).

Answer (score 1):

The other Jonas (before he changed his name) gave several impressive answers:

- [Why do manga characters love to eat a lot of food?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124257/4918) As someone who doesn't know much about animé and manga, this answer gives a nice glimpse into its culture.
- [What is the first instance of a person gaining powers from radiation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125262/4918) Comics history.
- [Warhammer story that covers someone's transition from human to ghoul](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126587/4918). Nice detective work to prove that something is never described in a long book series.
- [Looking for a young adult book about an audiovisual recording device that can rewind and fast-forward past the limits of the recording](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126665/4918)  FuzzyBoots and Jonas together are unable to verify if this answer is right, because the book is completely inaccessible, but it looks like a good candidate.

Other highlights of the quarter:

- <del>([Why is Gollum's memory so selective?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92524/4918) ATB answers why Gollum doesn't know he's a hobbit.)</del> Update: sorry, I messed this one up, it was only edited this quarter, not posted.
- <del>([Why did Rowling seemingly make light of the house-elf situation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122285/4918) Jason Baker's answer explains that Hermione's efforts were for a good cause but utterly misguided, confirmed by a Rowling interview.)</del> This one is from the last quarter.
- [Is there a mind probe lying around in the middle of this Death Star meeting room?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128792/4918) Nice question noticing a setting detail in the film by The Dark Lord, with a good answer.
- [I remember a children's book with math and a world inside a book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132378/4918) Story-id well done, by user14111.

Comment: ARGH! Posted this too late.

Comment: @amaranth: that's close enough for me to count as "the other Jonas".  "Jonah" is the name of a biblical prophet, and "Jonas" is a variant for that name when it's transferred through Latin.